# Scanning window across boolean values, return max window

Tags: r

I have a list of participants with 10 measurement occasions each. A boolean value is assigned to each measurement occasion. I want to scan the 'boolean' column, 4 measurements at a time (1->4, 2->5, 3->6, etc.). I want to figure out in which window I have the maximum amount of '1' values, with the result being stored in the 'MaxWindow' column.

An example of what it should look like is provided below:

[image]

note: If the max can be observed in more than one window, I want to simply take the window furthest in the scan.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rollsumr` from `zoo` to get rolling sum for a particular window size and select the last max using `which` + `max` and create a `maxwindow` column for each `Participant`.

```
library(dplyr)

win_size <- 4

df %>%
  group_by(Participant) %>%
  mutate(sum = zoo::rollsumr(Boolean, win_size, fill = NA), 
         maxwindow = {i <- max(which(sum == max(sum, na.rm = TRUE)));
                      paste(i - win_size + 1, i, sep = '-')})

#   Participant Measurmeant Boolean   sum maxwindow
#         <dbl>       <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>    
# 1           1           1       1    NA 5-8      
# 2           1           2       1    NA 5-8      
# 3           1           3       0    NA 5-8      
# 4           1           4       0     2 5-8      
# 5           1           5       1     2 5-8      
# 6           1           6       1     2 5-8      
# 7           1           7       1     3 5-8      
# 8           1           8       0     3 5-8      
# 9           1           9       0     2 5-8      
#10           1          10       0     1 5-8
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Participant = 1, Measurmeant = 1:10, 
                 Boolean = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```